# Codeigniter insert multiple selected values into database

Tags: codeigniter, insert

I've been spent lots of time in this multiple selected array which is hold several values in a multiple dropdown box, and what I want is insert selected values into table.

Let say I been selected `1,2,3` from dropdown box, when I  print_r($this->input->post('category'))`, its shown

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 2 )
```

however when insert into table, its only has the last value is inserted instead of all 3 values.

Here is **View** to select several values:

```
$category = array(
    'name' => 'category',
    'id' => 'category'
);

<select name="category[]" id="<?php echo $category['id'] ?>" multiple="multiple">
                    <?php
                    foreach($catOpts as $catOpt)
                    {
                        $selected = ($this->input->post('category')==$catOpt->category_name) ? 'selected' : '';
                        echo '<option value="'.$catOpt->category_id.'" '.$selected.'>'.$catOpt->category_name.'</option>';
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>
```

In **Controller**, I pass values to validation and if validation valid,:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('category[]', 'Category', 'required');

if($this->form_validation->run()) { // validation ok

    if(!is_null($data = $this->db_model->save_listing(          
        $this->form_validation->set_value('category[]')
    ))) { // success

    //some message to acknowledge success created.

    }
}
```

**Model** to insert into table:

```
function save_listing($category)
{

    $data = array(
        'category_id' => $category
    );

    $this->db->insert('listing', $data);

    return TRUE;

}
```

I do not know how to passes all values (array) into controller `$this->form_validation->set_value('category[]')` and then perform model function `save_listing()` and save all values into its column in database.

Please help to solve my problem and I has been browse through lots of forum but no luck to get solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When your field is an array you have to:

```
$data= array();

while( $v = $this->form_validation->set_value("field[]") )
{
    $data[] =  $v;
}
```

if you don't, it return the last value.

You also can get the values by `$this->input->post('fields')` but your sanities rules will not be applied to the values, like htmlspecialchars.

Of course, that's not specified into the doc, like other things..

Source /system/libraries/Form_validation.php:

```
/**
 * Get the value from a form
 *
 * Permits you to repopulate a form field with the value it was submitted
 * with, or, if that value doesn't exist, with the default
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   string  the field name
 * @param   string
 * @return  void
 */
public function set_value($field = '', $default = '')
{
    if ( ! isset($this->_field_data[$field]))
    {
        return $default;
    }

    // If the data is an array output them one at a time.
    //     E.g: form_input('name[]', set_value('name[]');
    if (is_array($this->_field_data[$field]['postdata']))
    {
        return array_shift($this->_field_data[$field]['postdata']);
    }

    return $this->_field_data[$field]['postdata'];
}
```